# VSCode /w. Prettier in TypeScript Monorepo

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I am currently using Prettier via VSCode Extension in a Monorepo Setup. The Problem is that Prettier does not fully work in my `api` folder. It does not respect the default line width and semicolons dont get automatically apended. Weirdly my `www` folder is working as usual and I dont have any missing Prettier feature.

Prettier config is set global via "*User Settings*" in VSCode.

- `www` - NextJS
- `api` - Apollo Server

```
|--- api
    |--- package.json
    |--- tsconfig.json 
    |--- server.ts
|--- www
    |--- pages
         |--- index.tsx
    |--- package.json
    |--- tsconfig.json
```

**www / tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  }
}
```

**api / tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the [`.prettierrc`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html) to the root of your project, with all the options that you would like to have.